# how to get values from server.js to controller in app directory on nodeJs and compoundjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, environment-variables

am new to nodeJs,

i declare a variable in server.js as

```
 var globals = module.exports = function getLimits() {

params = {};
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV == "production")
 {
  params.limits = 2;
 }
 else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development")
 {
      params.limits = 4;     
 } else 
 {
    params.limits = 6;  
 }

return params.limits
```

}

in  my controller on app directory am trying to get value of params.limits by using

```
compound.globals
```

but i didnt is there anyway to get value global on my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use `module.exports` with a custom property to expose the function:

```
module.exports.foo = function getlimits() {
```

then, reference it as such in the controller:

```
var bar = require('foo');
```